# Loop over months and apply a function

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, repeat

Hi I would like to loop over months and for each subset apply a function,

1 - (1 - se * p2)^df$n

Do you have any alternative to a for loop? Or would you suggest a better way to code it with a loop?
This is just a fake example as the real database is quite huge and it is annoying to loop over 12 months
The column month is

Thanks in advance

```r
rm(list = ls())

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
#> Error: RStudio not running
getwd()
#> [1] "C:/Users/Angela/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp21Zbwk/reprex-19b06a781308-waspy-bunny"

#load required packages 
library(mc2d)
#> Loading required package: mvtnorm
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mc2d'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     pmax, pmin
library(gplots)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'gplots'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     lowess
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(99)
iters<-1000

df<-data.frame(id=c(1:30),month=c(1:6,1,6,4,1,5,2,3,2,5,4,6,3:6,4:6,1:5,5),n=rpois(30,5))

df$n[df$n == "0"] <- 3
se<-rbeta(iters,96,6)
epi.a<-rpert(iters,min=1.5, mode=2, max=3)
p=0.2
p2=epi.a*p

##my try the idea is to loop over the months 

results<-data.frame(m1=numeric(iters))
results<-cbind(results,rep(results[1],5))
colnames(results)<-paste("m", sep = "_", 1:6)

for (j in 1:6) {
  for (i in 1:iters) {
    if (df$month[i]== "1")results$m_1[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
    else if (df$month[i]== "2")results$m_2[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
    else if(df$month[i]== "3")results$m_3[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
    else if(df$month[i]== "4")results$m_4[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
    else if(df$month[i]== "5")results$m_5[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
    else if(df$month[i]== "6")results$m_6[i]<- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i]
  }
  
}
#> Error in if (df$month[i] == "1") results$m_1[i] <- 1 - (1 - se[i] * p2[i])^df$n[i] else if (df$month[i] == : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You don't need a nested for loop, because you have not used `j` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop in R is very slow, because the interpreter can not use vectorization here. However, you can create a table of all possible combinations and calculate the result in a new column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

expand_grid(
  j = seq(6),
  i = seq(10)
) %>%
  mutate(
    res = map2_dbl(j, i, ~ .x + .y**2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 60 × 3
#>        j     i   res
#>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     1     1     2
#>  2     1     2     5
#>  3     1     3    10
#>  4     1     4    17
#>  5     1     5    26
#>  6     1     6    37
#>  7     1     7    50
#>  8     1     8    65
#>  9     1     9    82
#> 10     1    10   101
#> # … with 50 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi @danlooo thanks for your help .. but I do struggle to understand how can I implement this approach with my dataframe and function . Would you mind to post related to my dataframe? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that avoids `for` loops. The calculations of `p2` and `m` are vectorized and the `results` are output in a `tidyverse` pipe that reshapes those values, `m`, to wide format.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(mc2d)
  library(tidyverse)
})
set.seed(99)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:30,
  month = c(1:6, 1, 6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3:6, 4:6, 1:5, 5),
  n = rpois(30, 5)
)
iters <- nrow(df)

df$n[df$n == "0"] <- 3
se <- rbeta(iters, 96, 6)
epi.a <- rpert(iters, min = 1.5, mode = 2, max = 3)
p <- 0.2
p2 <- epi.a*p

m <- 1 - (1 - se * p2)^df$n
results <- data.frame(month = df$month, m)

results %>%
  arrange(month) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = n,
    names_from = month,
    names_glue = "m_{.name}",
    values_from = m
  ) %>%
  select(-n)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>      m_1    m_2    m_3    m_4   m_5    m_6
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  0.970  0.623  0.905  0.998 0.929  0.980
#> 2  0.912  0.892  0.736  0.830 0.890  0.862
#> 3  0.795  0.932  0.553  0.958 0.931  0.798
#> 4  0.950  0.892  0.732  0.649 0.777  0.743
#> 5 NA     NA     NA      0.657 0.980  0.945
#> 6 NA     NA     NA      0.976 0.836 NA    
#> 7 NA     NA     NA     NA     0.740 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

The code above can be rewritten as a function and then run the function `iter` times with `replicate`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(mc2d)
  library(tidyverse)
})

sim_one <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:30,
    month = c(1:6, 1, 6, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3:6, 4:6, 1:5, 5),
    n = rpois(30, 5)
  )
  nr <- nrow(df)
  
  df$n[df$n == "0"] <- 3
  se <- rbeta(nr, 96, 6)
  epi.a <- rpert(nr, min = 1.5, mode = 2, max = 3)
  p <- 0.2
  p2 <- epi.a*p
  
  m <- 1 - (1 - se * p2)^df$n
  results <- data.frame(month = df$month, m)
  
  results %>%
    arrange(month) %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    mutate(n = row_number(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = n,
      names_from = month,
      names_glue = "m_{.name}",
      values_from = m
    ) %>%
    select(-n)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Then run the function above, changing `iters` to the value you want, like this:

```
set.seed(99)

iters <- 2
sim_list <- replicate(iters, sim_one(), simplify = FALSE)

sim_list[[1]]
#> # A tibble: 7 × 6
#>      m_1    m_2    m_3    m_4   m_5    m_6
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  0.970  0.623  0.905  0.998 0.929  0.980
#> 2  0.912  0.892  0.736  0.830 0.890  0.862
#> 3  0.795  0.932  0.553  0.958 0.931  0.798
#> 4  0.950  0.892  0.732  0.649 0.777  0.743
#> 5 NA     NA     NA      0.657 0.980  0.945
#> 6 NA     NA     NA      0.976 0.836 NA    
#> 7 NA     NA     NA     NA     0.740 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas thank you for your help, I do have one question why are there NA? The idea is to have 10000 values for each column as the number of iters

Comment: @Anjeline If in the real data set all months have the same number of values, then there will be no `NA`'s. In the example you have posted, this was not the case, hence the `NA`'s. But function `pivot_wider` has a `values_fill` argument that you can set to another value, if you want to.

Comment: Hi @Rui Barradas .. no they do not have the same number of records but I need to use 10000 iters to simulate the results thus I need 10000 values for each month at the end  .. I am not sure if your approach can be adapted sine you iters= the number of rows in the df .. while I need 10000 iters. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Anjeline Now the simulation runs `iter` times. Adjust the value to  the number of simulations you want.

Comment: I tried your code with iters <- 10000 but I got the following problem:
#> Warning in (1 - se * p2)^df$n: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter
#> object length
#> Error in data.frame(month = df$month, m): arguments imply differing number of rows: 30, 1000

Comment: @Anjeline What did you run, the `replicate` instruction near the end? In order to make the code clearer I have changed `iters` to `nr` (num rows) *in the function*. Can you copy the function and the `replicate` code and give it a run?

Comment: the thing is that I need to use iters=1000 also inside rbeta() and rpert() instead of nr

Comment: @Anjeline I believe you don't need `iters` in `rbeta` and `rpert`, with the code I posted in the end you will have as many monthly values as there are `iters`. The way to get those values will be different they will be there.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I was trying to run your code with an additional variables in the dataframe ( a categorical one) which I should use later to perform a similar simulation .. however I am not able to keep  the column inside the results .. could you help me with that (I'll create a new post since the example is too long for a comment

Comment: @Anjeline Post the question, then, and a link here, I'll give it a look.

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149976/pivot-wider-does-not-keep-all-the-variables @Rui Barradas